# Is there any way to split all words in python?

Tags: python, string, split

I want to take an input and split all input with ",".

For example the input is:

```
Hello World
```

and I want to convert this to:

```
H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,l,d
```

Answer (score 6):

```
s = "Hello World"
splat = ','.join(s)
print(splat)
```

Output:

```
H,e,l,l,o, ,W,o,r,l,d
```

If you want this without the spaces, then simply remove the spaces before you `join` the remaining letters.  Look up how to use `replace`.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension, you can pass any iterable to `str.join`, including strings, so `','.join(s)` is enough!

Answer (score 1):

```py
word = 'Hello World'
result = word.replace(' ', '').replace('', ',')[1:-1]
```

Result has the value `H,e,l,l,o,W,o,r,l,d`

Answer (score 1):

do this from char to char and ignore space in advanced.

```
def split_word(input_string, spliter)
    output = ""
    for c in input_string.replace(' ',''):
        output = c + spliter
    return output[:-1]

split_word('Hello World', ',')
```